# how to update room status after insert using php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have two tables are tblroom and tblrent. How can i update a status field of table room after insert to table rent. Insert is work fine but update is not working. Here are my codes.

```
if($_POST) {    

    $validator = array('success' => false, 'messages' => array());
    $cusName = $_POST['cusName'];
    $room_num = $_POST['room_num'];
    $strDate = $_POST['strDate'];
    $book = $_POST['book'];
    $fctStatus = $_POST['fctStatus'];

    //insert values to database
    $sql = "INSERT INTO tblrent (name, room, start_date, booking, status) 
    VALUES ('$cusName', '$room_num', '$strDate', '$book', '$fctStatus')";
    $query = $connect->query($sql);

    //update the room status
    $update = "UPDATE tblrooms SET status ='$fctStatus' WHERE rNumber=$room_num";
    $query2 = $connect->query($update);

        if($query === TRUE) {           
            $validator['success'] = true;
            $validator['messages'] = "Successfully Added";      
        } else {        
            $validator['success'] = false;
            $validator['messages'] = "Error while adding the Customer information";
        }
    // close the database connection
    $connect->close();
    echo json_encode($validator);
}
```

Comment: Use SQL join to achieve your goal

Comment: "UPDATE tblrooms SET status ='".$fctStatus."' WHERE rNumber=$room_num";

Try this. $fctStatus value may not be take coz it is in single quote.

Comment: any error showing??

Comment: echo $update; die; before execute and run the query first in your database and check what issue is coming.

Comment: Firstly, you should use prepared statements. You are querying without even checking if the variables are empty or not. And did you check `$update` variable by printing the query? What error are you getting on update query?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should try showing the error message causing your issue. Also is the `$room_num` an integer? if it isn't then you might want to wrap it in quotes in your update statement. `$update = "UPDATE tblrooms SET status ='$fctStatus' WHERE rNumber='$room_num'";`

Note: you shouldn't be passing values directly from an input into a query as malicious input could be entered to and you might become a victim of [SQL Injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp). Consider using [prepared statements (PDO)](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp) or properly filtering and preparing the input first before passing it into the query.

```
if($_POST) {    

$validator = array('success' => false, 'messages' => array());
$cusName = $_POST['cusName'];
$room_num = $_POST['room_num'];
$strDate = $_POST['strDate'];
$book = $_POST['book'];
$fctStatus = $_POST['fctStatus'];

//insert values to database
$sql = "INSERT INTO tblrent (name, room, start_date, booking, status) 
VALUES ('$cusName', '$room_num', '$strDate', '$book', '$fctStatus')";
$query = $connect->query($sql);

//update the room status
//Note the quotes around the $room_num which should be used if it isn't an integer
$update = "UPDATE tblrooms SET status ='$fctStatus' WHERE rNumber='$room_num'";
$query2 = $connect->query($update);
    //check if the insert query worked
if($query === TRUE) {           
    $validator['success'] = true;
    $validator['messages'] = "Successfully Added";      
} else {        
    $validator['success'] = false;
    $validator['messages'] = "Error while adding the Customer information" . $connnect->error;
}
    //check if the update query worked
if ($query2 === TRUE) {
    echo "Room status updated successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error updating room status: " . $connnect->error;
}

// close the database connection
$connect->close();
echo json_encode($validator);
}
```